# I can't use method get in blade file in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I used the get method in laravel's blade file but when displaying in the browser, it says

> Undefined index: page.

This is my code:

```
$startPage = $_GET['page'];
```

Comment: What's the url you're calling? Is `page` set there? (Obviously not)

Comment: Is this is your ajax method call ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if it exists with `isset($_GET['page'])`.

For blade:

```php
@if (isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'])
  {{ $_GET['page'] }}
@endif
```

For PHP:

```php
$startPage = '';
if (isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page']) {
  $startPage = $_GET['page'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Full my code:
<table border="1">
    <?php
        $xml = simplexml_load_file('../xml/QuanLyDoAnTotNghiep.xml');
        $startPage = $_GET['page'];
        $perPage = 10;
        $currentRecord = 0;
        $DeTai = $xml->DeTai;
    ?>
    <tr>
    <td>Mã đề tài</td>
    <td>Nội dung đề tài</td>
    <td>Link tải về</td>
    </tr>
    @foreach($DeTai as $key)
        <?php $currentRecord += 1;?>
        @if($currentRecord > ($startPage * $perPage) && $currentRecord < ($startPage * $perPage + $perPage))
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $key->MaDT }}</td>
            <td>{{ $key->NoiDungDeTai }}</td>
            <td>{{ $key->LinkTaiVe }}</td>
        </tr> 
        @endif
    @endforeach
      <tr>
          <td colspan="10" align="center" style="margin-left: 100px">
                <?php 
                for ($i = 0; $i <= ($currentRecord / $perPage); $i++) {
                   echo("<a style='margin-left: 10px' href='http://localhost:9000/dashboard/index.php?page=".$i."'>".($i+1)."</a>");
                }?>
          </td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please **edit** your question and paste relevant code there. Then please remove this answer

Answer (score 0):

Firstly please don't use php in blade templates. Secondly check get key before using.

According to your code:

```
$startPage = $_GET['page'] ?? 1;
```

For right way

In your method

```
...
public function myMethod()
{
$xml = simplexml_load_file('../xml/QuanLyDoAnTotNghiep.xml');
        $startPage = request('page') ?? 1;
        $perPage = 10;
        $currentRecord = 0;
        $deTai = $xml->DeTai;
    return view('my_blade_template',compact('deTai','startPage','perPage','currentRecord'));

}
...
```

Comment: Thanks! @YILMAZ
I want to paginate in laravel using xml file. Can you help me!